# Модификаторы доступа

Tags: java, android

Есть код:

```
Button pls,min,pro,del;
EditText arg1,arg2;
TextView result;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pls = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPls);
    min = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMin);
    pro = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUmn);
    del = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDel);

    pls.setOnClickListener(this);
    min.setOnClickListener(this);
    pro.setOnClickListener(this);
    del.setOnClickListener(this);

    arg1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNum1);
    arg2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNum2);

    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

}
```

Это кусочек кода из одной активности, код чисто для примера.

Во всех примерах, которые я видел, объявления переменных

```
Button pls,min,pro,del;
EditText arg1,arg2;
TextView result;
```

не помечают модификатором `private`. Почему так?

Я просто знаю, что в *java* это дурной тон, если переменные не нужны, кроме как в данном классе, их помечают как приватные.

Comment: Спросите у авторов этих примеров ,почему они не парятся насчет этого. Я, например, стараюсь всегда выставлять модификаторы.

Comment: @metalurgus в общем я правильно понимаю что здесь те же правила и открытая переменная - уязвимость моей программы.

Comment: А откуда этот код, можно конкретную ссылку? Вообще переменная package-private не считается уязвимостью. Считается, что ваш пакет контролируете только вы. К примеру, при активном SecurityManager, вы не достанете это значение через reflection.

Comment: Я бы не называл это уязвимостью, т. к. рефлексии по большому счету наплевать на модификаторы доступа...

Comment: @TagirValeev вот ссылка http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/54-urok-19-pishem-prostoj-kalkuljator.html

Comment: @metalurgus, с SecurityManager'ом не наплевать.

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirovich, ясно. Ну да, тут могли бы и подписать `private`, причин не писать я не вижу. Не всегда тюториалы крутые программисты пишут, у крутых программистов обычно дела поважнее есть :-)

Comment: @TagirValeev да,я знаю, просто прочитал пару книгу, по java,а теперь попутно читаю эти статьи, чтобы потом можно было книгу по android без трудов прочесть.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот официальный  [code style](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html) и как видно, там не сказано что модификаторами доступа можно пренебречь. Так что авторы примеров просто упростили.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо)